# read list or map using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list populated from my Controller and added to model object, I am trying to access the values of list at the client side using jquery. Is there a way of retreiving the values of list or a map at client side using jquery. Below is my code.

In Controller.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("username");
list.add("password");
mav.addObject("list", list);
```

In js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var command = "${list}";
    alert("comand" + command);
</script>
```

alert gives o/p as [username,password], How can I iterate over list and retrieve those values using jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is command type is an array? [username,password] looks like an array. If so you can iterate over `for (var i = 0; i < command.length; i++) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return type of your mvc action to JsonResult. So your mvc method should look like:

```
public JsonResult MyMethod()
{
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("username");
        list.add("password");
        mav.addObject("list", list);
}
```